# % of Queue and % of Cluster difference in yarn ui for MR/TEZ/SPARK jobs run

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, apache-tez

While debugging the TEZ/SPARK/MR jobs I can see the below jobs details in YARN UI.

[image]

does any one please help me with % of Queue & % of Cluster stats, since it showing 1815% usage ?

Answer (score 1):

% of cluster is stat, that is telling you how much resources does your job take from cluster.

% of queue tells you, how much of Absolute Configured Capacity does your query take.

Example:

your cluster has 1000GB of memory and two queues.
QueueA has Absolute configured capacity of 1%, with max capacity of 100%.
QueueB has Absolute configured capacity of 99% with max capacity of 100%.

If you run query in queueA, you are guaranteed you get at least 10GB of memory, but depending on the cluster load, you can get up to 1000GB of memory.

That would mean that when you run query in queueA and you get 20GB of memory, you will be using 200% of the queue, but 2% of the cluster.